# Youtube 301 views. What is statistical about it?

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

Apparently any new video on YouTube seems to freeze at 301 views for a period of time before the actual views start reflecting. [The reason](http://www.businessinsider.in/This-Is-Why-All-New-YouTube-Videos-Get-Exactly-301-Views/articleshow/21880671.cms) seems to be that youtube during this time "figures" out if the views are actual views & not automated by some bot.

This approach seems slightly weird. Why do this only for new videos? What about older videos? While these question are not appropriate here (they are not stats related). My question right now for this forum is specific to this quote from [this article](http://www.businessinsider.in/This-Is-Why-All-New-YouTube-Videos-Get-Exactly-301-Views/articleshow/21880671.cms).

> So YouTube pauses the counter at 301 views while its systems subject
>   the video — and its cached duplicates on servers all over the world —
>   to a statistical process that verifies the traffic.

Whats this "statistical" process that's referred here?

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a Youtube/Google policy, we can't know the true answer unless a Google representative speaks up. My guess is that they are referring to statistics that compare the likelihood of a typical person/family viewing their own videos against what the tracker reported. And they do the same thing for bots.

If most people sharing their videos with family (thus have the same IP address) results in an average of say, 10 views, and the tracker shows 100 views from that IP address, then something's up.

If the user has GoogleAdSense installed, they could earn money by just replaying their own videos over and over again or installing a bot to do that for them. Obviously Google doesn't want to pay these people money for "fake" page views.

As for why they picked the number 301 over another lower figure, I'm guessing that the 300 mark is where the AdSense dollars kick in. I'm not an AdSense user, so I don't know if that's factually true.

In short, I think they use statistics because they don't want to use computing power to match IP addresses. It's cheaper and easier to go by stats and just spend computing resources on detecting bots.

Comment: This looks like a reasonable answer to me.  I would also like to add, it is likely they look at the distribution of views over time to make sure that there is no systematic trend that a simple bot might create.  Although bots could certainly be made to appear to randomly watch a video, it would be an easy first step to remove "stupid" bots who systemically view the video.